# USB not detected and can't perform actions on it

Tags: ubuntu, storage, gparted, removable-storage, gnome-disks

While installing ChromeOS Flex into a machine, the installation process froze and we had to stop the installation. Now, the USB is not recognized in any machine, no matter if Windows or Linux.

When executing `df -h`, the device does not show up. However, it does show up when executing `lsusb` as `Bus 001 Device 008: ID ffff:1201`.

Additionally, on Ubuntu 20.04, I've tried using GParted, but the device is not detected.
[image]

However, it does appear in Disks.
[image]

As you can see, I can't perform any action on the device through Disks.

Is there any solution to this? How can the USB be recovered?

Thanks in advance.